# Why does comparing same string gives dfferent result?

Tags: java

When I compare string s1 and s2 it give equal result but with s3 it gives a different result

```
String s1="Hello"
String s2="Hello"
String s3=new String("Hello");
```

### Output

```
s1==s2 //true
s1.equals(s2) //false
s1==s3 //false
s1.equals(s3) //true
```

why does it produce different output even if the string is the same?

Comment: `s1.equals(s2)` is `true`. How did you test when it produced `false`?

Comment: You essentially never need to use `new String(String)`. Strings are immutable, so there is no need to have distinct instances with the same value.